# Logging HL7 Messages in BizTalk Pipeline

Tags: logging, biztalk, hl7

The HL7 flow uses MLLP adapter in BizTalk. There is also the Accelerator provided by Microsoft which can change the format of the HL7 message to an XML format for it to be processed.

When it comes to logging the HL7 messages, options available are storing it to the database or storing it to a file location by coding this as Pipeline Components.

Is it possible to store a copy of the HL7 message on a separate MSMQ queue so that other options for logging can be considered? If so, what would be the approach? I know there is the MSMQ adapter but with HL7, the appropriate adapter would be MLLP (For the Microsoft provided additional tools, namely BTAHL7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can easily use msmq adapter to send the message to msmq queue. All you need is a send port with Msmq adapter and with hl7 assembler pipeline so that when message reaches to queue it’s raw hl7. And then you can read the message from queue to save it anywhere u want. If required you can again disassemble from queue or just use a custom component for logging.

Comment: I meant use MLLP adapter but have a pipeline component which uses MSMQ to put it in the queue. I understand it can be done the other way, it's with the use of MLLP adapter, is that possible?

Comment: MLLP adapter should be used while receiving hl7 or sending hl7 on a tcp/ip port but you can use msmq adapter to send it msmq queue. If you really have to do it within a pipeline component then you need to use System.Messaging class in .net to send msg to queue. But I wouldn’t recommend to do it. As you can subscribe to hl7 on a msmq send port to send it queue withou any custom development.

Answer (score 2):

**HOLD ON!**

There are a number of regulatory and business issues with handling HL7 and you should not just log them randomly.

My very strong recommendation is **don't do this** until the business provides details on **exactly** how messages should be retained (if even so) and how they plan to comply.  Then you will know exactly what to do.

Comment: This is more for proof of concept and exploring the capabilities that BizTalk provides.